# Mount ext2 as totally readonly system from busybox

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, mount, busybox

I'm using ext2 FS on my embedded device (busybox) with readonly mode. But, when I check FS if its true readonly system. I found strange things: When I type `cat /proc/mounts`

```
rootfs / rootfs RW 0 0
/dev/root / ext2 ro,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
...
```

But in: /boot/grub/menu.lst

```
kernel=/boot/bzimage root=/dev/sda1 ro
```

in fstab:

```
/dev/root / ext2 ro,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

in inittab:

```
null::sysinnit:/bin/mount -a
```

/bin/mount:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (RW)
/dev/root on / type ext2 (ro,relatime,errors=continue)
```

I can't understand why rootfs mounted as RW (in case `/proc/mounts` and `/bin/mount`), and why arguments for mounting from fstab doesn't correspond to arguments in`/bin/mount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rootfs` is the initial root filesystem at `/`.  It is in RAM only, and is unreachable after `/dev/root` has been mounted over it.

[/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)

Comment: I have problems with ext2 FS when my device suddenly restart or power down, so I'm searching why ext2 in readonly still lose reference to inode. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: And additional question, why in fstab file: noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1 but after mount: 
relatime,errors=continue 0 0

Comment: 1. Not related.  2. `/` is mounted by kernel, before anything has access to `/etc/fstab`.  Depending on your init setup, `/` is likely not re-mounted using `/etc/fstab`, and there may be ways to pass command-line parameters like `roottype` and `rootflags` to affect the initial mount.